# preview elements in the same page after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, embed

I am trying to preview the files in the same page using the < embed> tag after clicking on them.
I found this way of displaying the directories from the file-system, but after I click on a file, either it downloads directly(ppt, pdf...) or opens in new page(jpeg, png)
help!
This is a screenshot of the result:[Screenshot of webpage after dropping a file direcory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yg9l3.png)

this is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Drag files and/or directories to the box below!</p>

<div id="dropzone">
<div id="boxtitle">
  Drop Files Here
</div>
</div>

<h2>Directory tree:</h2>

<ul id="listing">
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the javascript code:

```
let dropzone = document.getElementById("dropzone");
let listing = document.getElementById("listing");

function scanFiles(item, container) {
let elem = document.createElement("li");
elem.innerHTML = item.name;
container.appendChild(elem);

if (item.isDirectory) {
let directoryReader = item.createReader();
let directoryContainer = document.createElement("ul");
container.appendChild(directoryContainer);

directoryReader.readEntries(function(entries) {
    entries.forEach(function(entry) {
      scanFiles(entry, directoryContainer);
  });
});
}
}
dropzone.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
}, false);
dropzone.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
let items = event.dataTransfer.items;

event.preventDefault();
listing.innerHTML = "";

for (let i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
let item = items[i].webkitGetAsEntry();

if (item) {
    scanFiles(item, listing);
}
}
}, false);
```

Comment: Browsers can't read just any file extension. Many require them to be opened in specific applications such as all the MS Office extensions. Some can be converted to html through libraries but you would need to dig through them individually and sort out specifics for each type

Comment: Yes I understand, the last time I used the browser to preview ppt, pdf and jpeg files which is more than enough for me. what I used in the embed tag. Can you help with that please, because through the code I showed you, everything is hidden I have no idea how to implement the embed tag on html with and item that doesn't exist in my code

Comment: Running this locally seems to act a little different to running it online via a server/host. [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/xpebd53x/)

Comment: You can use regex to check the file format. Here is a quick example [**jsFIddle scanFiles()**](https://jsfiddle.net/ngy3m52o/) Notice how all images will display `"<-- IMAGE"` and have background of red for the purpose of demo. You can find those changes within the **scanFiles()** function.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I tried the code just now, but this is not my question, as I mentioned I'm trying to preview the files in the same page, not downloading or opening them in new tabs  @NewToJS

Comment: then you will need to find a way to create a `fake:` path for `item.fullPath`

Comment: Can you emphasise more please.

Comment: Maybe this might help if you combine this with what you are currently working with. Filter out the pdfs and use http://usefulangle.com/post/20/pdfjs-tutorial-1-preview-pdf-during-upload-wih-next-prev-buttons to display the preview. I haven't used it before but from what I can see of it, it looks like a good direction to go in.

Comment: his comment is just to get the commentator badge

Comment: This comment is just to get the commentator badge*

Comment: This comment is just to get the commentator badge*

Comment: This comment is just to get the commentator badge*

Comment: This comment is just to get the commentator badge*

Comment: This comment is just to get the commentator badge*

Comment: This comment is just to get the commentator badge*